# How to use ExpandablePanel when expanded child height is unknown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use this [ExpandablePanel](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable). And this is my code:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 150,
    child: ExpandablePanel(
        theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
          headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
          tapBodyToCollapse: true,
          iconPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18),
        ),
        header: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 10, bottom: 15),
          child: Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
        ),
        collapsed: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ", softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
        expanded: Column (
          children: [
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ", softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
          ],
        )
    ),
  )
```

The problem is that as I understand `ExpandablePanel` needs to be inside some box with fixed height. But I in `expanded: Column (...)` I can have many different children and I can't calculate their height (and I don't want to do it as it is a very bad way). So, now I get `A RenderFlex overflowed by 84 pixels on the bottom`. Could anyone say how to use `ExpandablePanel` when height of the expanded child is unknown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your widget in a [`SingleChildScrollView()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html):

```dart
 SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ExpandablePanel(
            theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
              headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
              tapBodyToCollapse: true,
              iconPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18),
            ),
            header: Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 10, bottom: 15),
              child: Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
            ),
            collapsed: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                softWrap: true,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
            expanded: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vehicula quam id nunc porttitor tincidunt a tincidunt sem. Sed dignissim varius urna, quis dignissim diam consequat ac. In non eleifend enim. Vivamus ut elit ante. Vivamus at risus vitae ligula viverra imperdiet. Morbi vel imperdiet lectus. Etiam quis lectus justo. Aliquam pulvinar leo at ligula iaculis euismod. Phasellus quis fringilla enim, at porttitor est. ",
                    softWrap: true,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
```